# Workflow changing every item in list instead of only the one being edited

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, designer-workflow

Currently I have a list with a workflow where users submit a form to get approval for shared drive. The problem is that if there are a few items pending because we are still verifying user info and if I approve one of them, all get approved.

How can I stop the workflow from editing every item in the list and just edit the one I'm approving?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello Anthony,

Can you post a picture of your workflow? is it a SharePoint Designer custom workflow or a Task approval workflow?

Comment: Alright I added the screenshots. It is a custom workflow made in Designer.

Comment: The workflow details do not show any steps which would be causing an update on all items, can you post a picture of your workflow configuration page? Is it set to start on an item created or item modified?

Comment: It is set to be able to be started manually and when an item is created. I added a screenshot. By the way, thank you so much for helping.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use 'Set' for 'CurrentItem:Status' column.. and make sure you update status inside a condition statement, currently you are updating a status outside any condition. Try and see if that resolves this issue.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and report back. By the way, I should set it like that in every stage or just in Accepted and Rejected?

Comment: I would suggest you to do it in every stage.

Comment: Sorry, I tried it and didn't work. The status column is changing in all items even when I select CurrentItem.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your workflow after making the edits I suggested in the comment above?

Comment: Here: 
https://s29.postimg.org/w58pfvl9j/image.png

https://s28.postimg.org/ph70f9am5/image.png

The little cutout part at the end is just the end workflow instruction but it didn't fit the screenshot.